# Get the Row Id to the JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In my web application, on change event I pass the data to the javascript function as.

```
<select onchange="sendInfo(this)" class="form-select js-dropdown" data-id='+counter+' name="Item_Id[' +counter +']" id="ItemId"' + counter + ' required="required" ' +
"</select>"
```

I want to get the `data-id` on the javascript variable. How can I pass this?

From the current code, it gets the selected Id. I want to get the `data-id` as well.

```
function sendInfo(e)
{
 console.log(e.value);
}
```

Comment: [`e.target.dataset.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your any attribute value with the help of [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) and also if you don't want to use it you can use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) for `data` attribute. check below code to get attribute value.

Let's say your html looks like this,

```
<select onchange="sendInfo(this)" class="form-select js-dropdown" data-id='+counter+' name="Item_Id[' +counter +']" id="ItemId"' + counter + ' required="required" ' +
"</select>"
```

Then you can do this in your JavaScript function,

```
function sendInfo(e)
{
  // using getAttribute()
  console.log(e.getAttribute('data-id'));

  // using dataset
  console.log(e.taget.dataset.id)
}
```